# Jmeter - How to see HTTP Request Sent (in order to debug errors)

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter test plan with multiple separate http calls (samplers). I am getting the same error with all the calls:

```
0,0,, Non HTTP response code: java.net.MalformedURLException, Non HTTP response message: Illegal character found in host: '/',EntSearchTests 1-1,test,fase,,784,0,1,1,null,0,0,0
```

Here is a representative portion of the jmx file (with some obfiscation) for one of the queries:

```
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">path.to.resource/myResouce</stringProp>
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8082</stringProp>
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/rest/status</stringProp>
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
```

By the way, I have to run this no-GUI, so I am running from command line with -LDEBUG to get as much data as possible. However, nowhere on the log file do I see useful information showing the assembled query (like something being run as a curl), but instead its all in pieces.

curl based calls to same endpoints from same server work fine. I am assuming there is some minor thing I need to tweak but not sure what it would be. Grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see it in the jmeter log file - add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

You will get something like:

[image]

More information: [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) You can also use a Listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) and configure it to save request data into a file.

[image]

Once your test is finished you will be able to open the file with View Results Tree listener and inspect request details.

Comment: thank you! simple data writer was perfect for my debugging. thanks!